Looking for an old game on Ubuntu I played when I was a kid
The game is like bomberman,I think it's 2D game and it's at least over a decade, the perspective is top-down, the characters in the game are sphere-shaped.
There's a feature is that if your character wounded, there will have a burnt scar on your character if I remember it correctly.
What is this game and how to install it in Ubuntu?

You may be looking for bomberclone, which is a clone of bomberman.
You can install it with the command
sudo apt install bomberclone



Alternatively, install atomic-bomberman using snap
sudo snap install atomic-bomberman

